# Scala, unsafeRunSync - why it needs to be call every time?

Tags: scala, scala-cats

I have a strange problem. I created two methods, which return `Lists`:

```
override def createContributorsList(url: String, params: String): F[List[Contributor]] = getContributorsFromClient(url, params).fold[List[Contributor]](_ => List(), res => res)

override def createReposList(organization: String, params: String): F[List[GitRepository]] = getReposFromClient(organization, params).fold[List[GitRepository]](_ => List(), res => res)
```

Now I want to call these methods (they connect to a `Git` repository and get contributors for a given organization):

```
val res = for {
    repos <- stats.createReposList("github", "")
    contr = repos.foreach(r => println(stats.createContributorsList(r.contributors_url,"").unsafeRunSync()))
  } yield (repos,contr)
 res.unsafeRunSync
```

As you see, I needed to call `unsafeRunSync` method twice to retrieve all the data. Why do I need to do it this way? Could it be done in another way? I think I should run `unsafeRunSync` only once - when I need to run program, not all the time.

Comment: what is the problem when you don't call it the first time? why do you have = instead of <- i n your for-comprehension

Comment: When I have `<-` I got error that it cannot resolve this symbol. What do you mean by "call it first time"?

Comment: I mean when you call unsafeRunSync in the for comprehension.

Comment: The problem is when you call unsafeRunSync the type of your expression is not IO anymore but Unit. And unit obviously has no flatmap/map.